# Is it possible to change react stack navigator pan gesture direction per screen?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am using react navigation library and I would like root stack view to be able to push some screens using right to left animation and some screens bottom to top. The main problem I have encountered is pan gesture for dismissing screens remains the same for all screens.

My routes:

```
const MODAL_ROUTES = [
  SceneKeys.EditProfileNavigator,
  SceneKeys.PicturePreview
]

const navigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    [SceneKeys.Main]: { // MAIN TAB BAR SCREEN
      screen: Main,
    },

    // Profile edit - comes from bottom, should not be dismissable by gestures
    [SceneKeys.EditProfileNavigator]: { 
      screen: EditProfileNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: false,
      }
    },

    // Picture preview - comes from bottom, should be dismissible with gesture top to bottom
    [SceneKeys.PicturePreview]: {
      screen: PicturePreview,
    },

    // comes from right, should be dismissible by swiping from the left
    [SceneKeys.Conversation]: {
      screen: Conversation
    }
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',

    transitionConfig: (transitionProps, prevTransitionProps) => {
      const isModal = MODAL_ROUTES.some(
        screenName =>
          screenName === transitionProps.scene.route.routeName ||
          (prevTransitionProps && screenName === prevTransitionProps.scene.route.routeName)
      )
      return StackViewTransitionConfigs.defaultTransitionConfig(
        transitionProps,
        prevTransitionProps,
        isModal
      )
    }
  },
)
```

Animations and transitions all work fine, however the main problem is that `PicturePreview` screen can be dismissed using left to right pan gesture - I want top to bottom pan gesture dismissal for this screen in particular.

Setting whole stack mode to `modal` makes `Conversation` screen transition from bottom, when I want right to left transition

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer that I was looking for, but I found solution to my problem.

Basically i wrapped my navigator to another modal navigator.

My Routes now look like this:

```
> Modal Stack navigator

  > Stack navigator

    > Tab Bar 
    > Conversation
    > Edit profile

  > Picture preview
```

Honestly if anyone wants to suggest how to fix my problem in other ways - please do